# Created observable doesn't emit anything

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I'm trying to create a function which returns `Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Any)>` using `RxAlamofire`:

```
class APIManager {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    func getResponse(credentialData: Credentials, ulr: String)->Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Any)>{
    let credentialData = "\(credentialData.username):\(credentialData.password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()
    let headers = ("Authorization", "Basic \(base64Credentials)")
    let header = HTTPHeaders.init(dictionaryLiteral: headers)
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        requestJSON(.get, ulr, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .subscribe(onNext: { response in
            observer.onNext(response)
            } ,


    onError: { error in
        observer.onError(error)
        },
    onCompleted: {},
    onDisposed: {}).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

}

The code into `onNext` is not executed; it's going through `onDisposed` only.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have subscribers for your `Observable`? It will not emmit anything without subscribers. Signals created using `Observable.create` are cold signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you wrapping `requestJSON` function with another Observable which is just forwarding the same element and error, when that function is already returning the Observable you need?.

Isn't this enough for you?

```swift
class APIManager {
    func getResponse(credentialData: Credentials, ulr: String) -> Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Any)> {
        let credentialData = "\(credentialData.username):\(credentialData.password)"
            .data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
        let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()
        let headers = ("Authorization", "Basic \(base64Credentials)")
        let header = HTTPHeaders.init(dictionaryLiteral: headers)
        return requestJSON(.get, ulr, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
    }
}
```

Comment: for this method this enough, but I have methods with the same problem in which I create new Observable:
```func signIn(with credentials: Credentials) -> Observable<User> {
        let aPIManager = APIManager()
        let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        return Observable.create { observer in
            aPIManager.getResponse(credentialData: credentials, ulr: "https://api.github.com/authorizations").subscribe{ event in
                observer.onNext(User())
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }```

Comment: Can't you just use `map` then? `return apiManager.getRespose(...).map { //create your User }`